# Visual Studio plugin to refactor (change) class namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Similar questions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174193/visual-studio-is-there-a-move-class-to-different-namespace-refactoring) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360320/refactor-namespace-in-visual-studio).  One is almost a year old, the other almost three.

Is there any **light** plugin for Visual Studio that moves a class into a new namespace?  Bonus points if it works for WPF/Silverlight user controls (by renaming their concomitant xmlns markup)

I don't want to dump resharper onto my IDE just for one feature.  I'm hoping someone knows of some light and simple plugin that does this.

Comment: If one is not easily available, might be an idea to write one.  Just an thought :)

Comment: You give me too much credit :)

Comment: Out of curiosity why wouldn't you want to use ReSharper? The only reason I can think of is you have a competing tool.

Comment: I tried ReSharper, I just didn't care for it.  Some of their features I liked, some I didn't.  I spent a lot of time customizing the features to just what I wanted, and when the trial ran out, I just didn't feel like spending the money to keep it.

Comment: I've never met someone who did not like resharper!

Comment: Then you met me too. I prefer CodeRush, is not intrusive, and doesn't replace Visual Studio features but add to them. The features are just what I need. However, the one thing lacking is really the namespaces refactoring, I find it a little poor.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say I know of an addin that can do this, however [the answers to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042344/how-to-output-namespace-in-t4-templates) ([see also](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984475%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)) detail how to generate a folder structure based namespace using the Visual Studio environment variable in T4 which I'm sure could be wrapped into a macro or addin. 
Please let me know if you have the time to package this up!